# "lshw -C disk" returns but prints nothing

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, livecd, dd

I am using an ubuntu live cd to help me recover some data off of a hard drive. I used `lshw -C disk` to find out which device I need to copy, `/dev/sda` in this case.

I am using `ddrescue -n` to try and recover some data from a failing hard drive.  It stops at 100GB of a 500GB hard drive. After it finishes `sudo lshw -C disk` does not print anything.

The next step in using `ddrescue` is to use `sudo ddrescue -r 1 /dev/sda`, but it reports there is no such file or directory.

What is going on; why is `lshw` failing to report anything?

Edit: Added sudo to relevant places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way in which your disk is failing is so bad that the kernel becomes unable to keep communicating with the disk.

There are probably a lot of errors concerning the disk in `/var/log/kern.log`. If you post its contents here, people might have tips to help you recover more. (Post only the part from the first disk error, presumably triggered during the `ddrescue -n`, to the point where the kernel deactivates `sda`; if there's a long and repetitive bit in the middle, it's ok to cut the repetitions.) But don't expect miracles, there's a chance that the last 400GB are simply beyond recovery without spending thousands of dollars on a professional service.

Comment: Well I am not willing to spend that much for little gain. I This all happened on a live cd so the log files no longer exist. I will rerun and post later today.

Answer (score 0):

Try running lshw as super user.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not being specific I was using sudo with the command.